Height 100%, still not spreading to the whole page?
So yesterday I decided to create a hand cricket game, but guess I messed up with its interface! I had set up a main tag in it whose height wasn't written yet, after adding the background to it, I got that I forgot to set height of the main tag. This is the code
Later i added the height in main as 100%
Still, when I ruined the code, the page looked the same
What can I do?


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3E3E3E;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: white;
}

main {
  padding: 5%;
  background: #3E3E3E;
}

.play-bot,
.play-friend,
.set-a-scenario,
.matches-log {
  width: 99%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #9933CC;
  color: #F5F5F5;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>HTML</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    Hand Cricket
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="play-bot">
      Play with a bot!
    </div>
    <div class="play-friend">
      Play with a friend!
    </div>
    <div class="set-a-scenario">
      Set a custom scenario!
    </div>
    <div class="matches-log">
      Matches log
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>




Try following code to your main tag:
main {
height: 90vh; /*set the full height of device but without overflowed by navbar*/
top: 10vh; /* if doesn't work try with margin-top */
padding: 5%;
background: #3E3E3E;
}


Because of the padding this does not scale properly.
